# Extracting line between two pattern using Sed and the next pattern should come in new paragraph in mac

Tags: macos, design-patterns, sed, between, extract

I want to extract all lines that comes between two citation. I want to include first sentence containing citation and should stop extraction when new citation comes. This process should continue till end of file. I am using Mac. The two pattens must be separated by blank lines or some dashed lines. This is my input data which i extracted using command (all lines come in new line.)

sed -n '/(*[1-2][0-9]{3})/,/^(*[1-2][0-9]{3})/p;/^(*[1-2][0-9]{3})/q'

Any personal bias by authors has to be hedged (Hyland, 1995).
Negative sentiment is politically particularly dangerous (Ziman, 1968), and some authors have documented the strategy of prefacing the intended criticism by slightly disingenuous praise (MacRoberts and MacRoberts, 1984).
This makes the problem of identifying such opinions particularly challenging.
This nonlocal expression of sentiment has been observed in other genres as well (Wilson et al., 2009; Polanyi and Zaenen, 2006).

---

But i want the output should come like this

---

Any personal bias by authors has to be hedged (Hyland, 1995).

Negative sentiment is politically particularly dangerous (Ziman, 1968), and some authors have documented the strategy of prefacing the intended criticism by slightly disingenuous praise (MacRoberts and MacRoberts, 1984).
This makes the problem of identifying such opinions particularly challenging.

This nonlocal expression of sentiment has been observed in other genres as well (Wilson et al., 2009; Polanyi and Zaenen, 2006).

Comment: It might be a good idea to provide an example of the input, as well.

Comment: I want the next pattern matched data should be separated by some separator so that u can find out easily that new it is new pattern. All the lines are coming in newline.

Comment: Still unclear. I think you want this: If a sentence contains a citation, start a new paragraph. If not, append it to the current paragraph. Is that correct?

Comment: yes. Whenever a line containing a  citation  comes, it should start in a new paragraph and all lines after this should be part of this paragraph. When a new line containing citation comes it should be shown in next paragraph and this process should continue. Need an urgent help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not insist on `sed`, it would be a lot easier to do in `awk`:

```
BEGIN { RS="\\. +"; }
/\(.*\)/ { if (acc) { print acc "\n" }; acc = $0 "."; next; }
{ if (acc) { acc = acc " " $0 "." } else { print $0 "."; } }
END { if (acc) { print acc; } }
```

Comment: what is acc... i am using mac. I think it should be extracting data between 2 patterns and the second pattern should not be included. After blank line the next pattern should come.

Comment: or u can say whenever a line containing citation comes. A new blank line should come before it.

Comment: `acc` (accumulator)  is a variable. Or do you mean `awk`? `awk` is a program for text processing, like `sed`, but more advanced. I assumed that it would be available if `sed` is.

Comment: but in this awk command... where i will put pattern  and where to pass the file name.

Comment: `awk -f program input`